# Disable Function in Javascript event DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have problem with javascript,
in my html code:

```
<input onclick="myFunction();" />

<script>
function myFunction(){
 //excecution of this fucntion
}
</script>
```

After clicking the input, the function runs. But I want myFunction to be disable after the first click, so when I click again, myFunction won't run.

Comment: pass `this` to `myFunction` and at the end do `this.disabled=true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set it to a empty function, after the code has executed.

```
function myFunction(){
   //(..) Some code
   myfunction = function(){}; // empty the function so nothing happens next time
}
```

Comment: @VinraGunantaPandia yes. That's what you want right?

Comment: not  exactly, but sometimes i neet to reactivated it

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the attribute

```
<input onclick="myFunction(this);" />

<script>
function myFunction(elem){
    // code here
    elem.removeAttribute('onclick')
}
</script>
```

or even better use event listeners

```
<input id="myInput" />

<script>
    document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);

    function myFunction(elem){
        // code here
        this.removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I wouldn't remove the attribute (not even sure whether that works) but do `this.onclick = null`

Comment: @Bergi - Removing the attribute works just fine in all browsers, it automatically also removes the property as inline `on...` attributes are mapped to the property. Of course, using `addEventListener` is much easier in my opinion

Comment: Yeah, `addEventListener` should be preferred, +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery (as You have included it in the tags), I'd go with [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
<input type="txt" class="my-input" />
```

```
function activateClick(){
    // single click:
    $('.my-input').one('click', function(){
        // do stuff ...
    });
}

// Activate single click on input element 
// Can be reactivated later on, using the same function (see DEMO):
activateClick();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0567b6a6/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean indicator to determine whether the function has already run or not. The advantage with this method is that it is easy to reset the function status at a later date.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick='func();'>Function</button>
</body>
<script>
var funcActive=true;
function func() {
if (funcActive) {
funcActive=false;
alert('func ran');
}
}
</script>
</html>
```